# How to close all dynamically created forms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

**How do I close all opened forms which are created on the fly?**

```vb
Sub OpenForms
   dim F as new frmForm1
   F.show

   dim F2 as new frmForm1
   F2.show
End Sub

sub CloseForms
'doesn't work, (forms are created in a dll and ".openforms" method is not available):
'For each f as Form in My.Application.OpenForms
' f.Close()
'Next
end Sub
```

I want to close all opened frmForm1 - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a list/collection and add all created forms to it. Then you can iterate through list/collection to close all. Here is example in C#:

```
List<frmForm1> _forms = new List<frmForm1>();

void OpenForms()
{
    var f1 = new frmForm1();
    _forms.Add(f1);

    var f2 = new frmForm1();
    _forms.Add(f2);

 }

void CloseForms()
{
    foreach (var form in _forms)
    {
        form.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> The My.Application.OpenForms property returns all open forms, regardless of which thread opened them. You should check the InvokeRequired property of each form before accessing it; otherwise, it might throw an InvalidOperationException exception. For more information, see [How to: Access All Open Forms of an Application (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172724.aspx)

Hope that helps.